# How do I get more units?

Tags: timber-and-stone

I've got roads leading out of three cardinal directions, a hall, 230 food and only 7 units. I also made my road intersect with my hall because I read that matters (picture below) but I'm still not getting any units migrating in. Is there anything I'm missing?

[image: Hall-road intersection]

Comment: I think you might be on to some sort of bug, the migrant arrival rate since 1.1 has decreased enormously.

Answer (score 3):

Migrants are completely random just like merchants. The more food you have the better. I have had games where I get migrants after 50 food and other games where I get my first migrant after 700 food. So the only way is to increase your food and be patient

Comment: [The more wealth and especially food you acquire, the more often you’ll have migrants coming in to join your settlement.](http://timberstonewiki.net/wiki/Migrant)

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you there is a migrant/food ratio, but it is still really random.

Answer (score 1):

The road size doesn't increase the chances of spawning migrants. The road size is to make sure no monsters or animals are blocking the path. Each road connected to a side of the map will increase spawn rate by 20-25% plus the amount of food you have in stock.

Go to this website created by TeoXD of T&S Forum. It will give full details on the matter.
https://timberandstone.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 0):

I believe in the latest versions that the road has to be 3 blocks wide.  I thought I would drop this here just in case anyone else comes by to find an answer.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? Provide info like why it has to be 3 blocks wide and not anything else.